# Problem Creating Bootable USB Drive - v12.04 - Win XP SP3 - Asus Eeepc 901

Tags: eeepc

Just another new guy in town trying to find his way around.

Let's cut to the chase:
I got this error after doing what is explained below the screen shot.
(First time posting a photo link in this manner as well.)
[image: error]

It says: "Universal USB Installer 1.8.9.6 Setup
Extract: error writing to file C:\DOCUME~1\CHADM~1.BAL\LOCALS~1\Temp\nse18.tmplpaypal.bmp"

I attempted to create a bootable USB drive (16GB SanDisk) using PenDriveLinux to run 12.04 on my Asus EeePC 901 netbook, but didn't have enough hard disk space to download the ubuntu .iso file.
So, I popped the USB into my Dell laptop to perform the iso file download.  Then, moved the USB drive back into the EeePC.
After selecting the .iso file from the USB drive, I got the above error.
What did I do wrong?

Thank you for reading and the support!

Comment: Questions on Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to Ubuntu. This is a Windows problem or related to pendrivelinux or related to your hardware ;)

Comment: Two things occur to me. 1) Did you remove the USB pendrive from the Dell  by dismounting it first, or did you just pull it out? 2) If there was not enough space on your EeePC for the iso file, it is unlikely that you'd be able to boot Ubuntu from the USB stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says: "Setup Extract: error writing to file C:\DOCUME~1\CHADM~1.BAL\LOCALS~1\Temp\nse18.tmplpaypal.bmp"

You still need to have some space in the hard drive to complete the installation because Universal USB Installer is trying to write in C:\

You can simply create the bootable USB in your Dell laptop.

Comment: That appears to have been the ticket!
Thanks a lot!  

I created the bootable USB drive on my Dell and now, after reconfiguring the boot settings on my netbook to boot from the removable drive, it boots into a black screen with a flashing cursor.  ...I'll play around with it some more.

Comment: Success!
I was trying to boot from the wrong USB device.
Actually, I don't think my SanDisk USB drive showed up in the list the first time.  We're in business.  Thank you for your help.